# android, String value isn't visible in debugger

Tags: java, android, debugging

I want to track the value of an edited text in android, I am using debug mode.

Here is a portion of code, I retrieve data from the user's input and I want to see it in the debugger.

```
    EditText personName=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);
    EditText number=findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
    Intent sendBack=new Intent();
    String sentName=personName.toString();
    Integer a=Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
    sendBack.putExtra("name", sentName);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, sendBack);
    Activity2.this.finish();
```

But, I noticed that the value returned by an integer (Number ) is shown in the debugger while the string ( plainText ) value isn't.

[image]

I want to be able to see the string's value like what is happening for the integer as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to do `String sentName=personName.getText().toString();` instead of `String sentName=personName.toString();`

Comment: I have added getText() and now I can visualize what data that comes from the user in the debugger, big thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the String is visible in the debugger. As you have performed `String sentName=personName.toString();`, the `EditText#toString` function is returing the all information about personName (EditText) instead of it's value.

The information of this EditText contains the id of view, location, size, package name, value, etc.

You can observe in your screenshot that the string starts with the package name of the EditText being used (i.e. "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText") followed by some other information like ObjectId, etc.

In case you just need to access the value inside this EditText just modify your code from `String sentName=personName.toString();` to `String sentName=personName.getText().toString();`

Comment: this solved my problem, big thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have done a typo in the first line you have written "personName" two times.
Check this line. `EditText personName=personName=findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);` Also, more specifically if you are using API level < 26. It is better you cast it to EditText like this as findViewById() method returns an integer value.
`EditText personName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);`And use  `String sentName = personName.getText()` to get the text data from EditText View.